# Show that sequence converges, hence find the limit.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, proof-verification, lp-spaces

[image]

**(a)**

$a\ge 0,b>0.$
By definition, $a\leq f(x)\leq b\implies a^m\leq f(x)^m \leq b^m\implies \int_{0}^{1}a^mdx\leq \int_{0}^{1}f(x)^mdx \leq \int_{0}^{1}b^mdx\implies (\int_{0}^{1}a^mdx)^{\frac{1}{m}}\leq (\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^mdx)^{\frac{1}{m}} \leq (\int_{0}^{1}b^mdx)^{\frac{1}{m}}\implies a\leq c_m \leq b. $

**(b)**$\int_0^1 f(x)^pdx\le(\int_0^1 f(x)^\frac{pq}{p}dx)^{\frac{p}{q}}(\int_0^1 1^\frac{1}{1-p/q}dx)^{1-\frac{p}{q}}$ 
$=(\int_0^1 f(x)^\frac{pq}{p}dx)^{\frac{p}{q}}$ 
$=(\int_0^1 f(x)^{q}dx)^{\frac{p}{q}}$
We know, $\frac{p}{q}<1$
so $c_n$ is increasing.
We know that $\lim_{p\to\infty}||f||_{p}=||f||_{\infty}$
so $c_n$ converges to $b$. Am I right?

Comment: Are there any parts you are particularly confused about or are unsure of?

Comment: (b) part of the question.